# Dynamic Array 2D in Python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I want to save some data from Twitter and I would to use a 2-dimensional array in order to save all hashtags in the first row and all external urls in the second one, with dynamic cols.

I've implemented this:

```
hashtag_extLink = 2 * [[]]

...
...

if field == "hashtag":
    hashtag_extLink[0].append(x)
elif field == "ext_link":
    hashtag_extlink[1].append(y)
else:
    pass
```

but, when I will print the hashtag_extLink using this statement:

```
for row in range(len(hashtag_extLink)):
    print("Row %d" % row)
    for col in range(len(hashtag_extLink[row])):
        print(hashtag_extLink[row][col], end='')
    print("")
```

I get:

```
Row 0
xy
Row 1
xy
```

that is the `append()` function add value to both rows.
How can I fix? Have I to use Numpy?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining a 2D array like this: `x = 2 * [[]]` puts the same list in both places in the container list as is happening in your case.

Try defining the array like `x = [[],[]]`

```
>>> x = [[],[]]
>>> x[0].append(1)
>>> x
[[1], []]
```

Comment: Solved in this way. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the sizes,

```
ar = []
for i in range(5):
   ar.append([])
   for j in range(2):
       ar[i].append(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Define Dynamic 2D array and initialized with 0 values

`def initialize_array(rows, cols): l1 = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range (rows)] print (l1)`